# Blazor MudTable RowTemplate - create two rows per data bounditem

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a `MudBlazor` table and for each data-bound Item, I was thinking I might display this using two rows where the first row spans multiple columns in the second row, *e.g.*:

```
-------------------------------------------
Property 1
-------------------------------------------
Property 2 | Property 3 | Property 4
-------------------------------------------
```

Is that possible using the `<RowTemplate>`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom component that renders the `td`'s:

#### Index.razor

```cs
@page "/"

<MudTable Items="@this.Items" Elevation="1">
  <RowTemplate>
    <CustomTd Item="@context"/>
  </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

@code {
  private List<Item> Items = new()
  {
    new() { Property1 = "Property 11", Property2 = "Property 12", Property3 = "Property 13", Property4 = "Property 14" },
    new() { Property1 = "Property 21", Property2 = "Property 22", Property3 = "Property 23", Property4 = "Property 24" },
    new() { Property1 = "Property 31", Property2 = "Property 32", Property3 = "Property 33", Property4 = "Property 34" }
  };
}
```

#### Item.cs

```cs
public class Item
{
  public string Property1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;

  public string Property2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;

  public string Property3 { get; set; } = string.Empty;

  public string Property4 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

#### CustomTd.razor

```cs
<MudTd>
  @this.Item.Property1
  <MudSimpleTable Elevation="0">
    <tr>
      <td>@this.Item.Property2</td>
      <td>@this.Item.Property3</td>
      <td>@this.Item.Property4</td>
    </tr>
  </MudSimpleTable>
</MudTd>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

which will render like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late on this one, but, I face the same issue today.
I solved using

> ChildRowContent tag

Check this link: https://www.mudblazor.com/components/table#table-with-related-data It shoould go to : Table With related data
If not scroll down until there.

Here a sample:

```
<MudTable Items="@Items" >
<HeaderContent>
    <MudTh>
       add your header here Or remove HeaderContent if you don't need it
    </MudTh>
</HeaderContent>
<RowTemplate>
    <MudTd  colspan="3">
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">
            @context.Property1
        </MudText>
    </MudTd> 
</RowTemplate>
<ChildRowContent> 
    <MudTd>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">
            @context.Property2
        </MudText>
    </MudTd> 
    <MudTd>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">
            @context.Property3
        </MudText>
    </MudTd>  
    <MudTd>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">
            @context.Property4
        </MudText>
    </MudTd>  
</ChildRowContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, we assume you have `List<Item>` name `myList`

```
<MudTable Items="myList">
   <HeaderContent>

   </HeaderContent>
   <RowTemplate>
      <MudTd>
         <MudButton Onclick="()=> context.IsShowChildren = !context.IsShowChildren">Hide/Show</MudButton>
      </MudTd>
   </RowTemplate>

   //Add this
   <ChildRowContent>
       @if(context.IsShowChildren)
       {
          <MudTr>
           //Your data here
          </MudTr>
       }
   </ChildRowContent>
</MudTable>
```

Sample model

```
public class Item
{
    public bool IsShowChildren { get; set; }
}
```